# Помогите понять что делает asm участок кода.

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте! Есть код-задача(из программы задачки). В программу вводят две строки(логин пароль\серийник). Какой должен быть серийник, чтобы программа прошла успешно?

Вот часть кода где происходит работа с этими строками:

```
.text:004012F9 sub_4012F9      proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_401123+113p
.text:004012F9                 push    ebp
.text:004012FA                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:004012FC                 push    esi
.text:004012FD                 push    edi
.text:004012FE                 lea     esi, String
.text:00401304                 lea     edi, String2
.text:0040130A                 xor     eax, eax
.text:0040130C                 xor     ecx, ecx
.text:0040130E                 mov     bl, 1Ah
.text:00401310
.text:00401310 loc_401310:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_4012F9+2Fj
.text:00401310                 cmp     byte ptr [esi], 0
.text:00401313                 jz      short loc_40132A
.text:00401315                 mov     al, [esi]
.text:00401317                 add     al, cl
.text:00401319                 xor     al, cl
.text:0040131B                 div     bl
.text:0040131D                 shr     ax, 8
.text:00401321                 add     al, 41h
.text:00401323                 mov     [edi], al
.text:00401325                 inc     edi
.text:00401326                 inc     esi
.text:00401327                 inc     ecx
.text:00401328                 jmp     short loc_401310
.text:0040132A ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:0040132A
.text:0040132A loc_40132A:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_4012F9+1Aj
.text:0040132A                 mov     byte ptr [edi], 0
.text:0040132D                 xor     eax, eax
.text:0040132F                 cmp     ecx, 0
.text:00401332                 jz      short loc_40134E
.text:00401334                 push    offset String2  ; lpString2
.text:00401339                 push    offset String1  ; lpString1
.text:0040133E                 call    lstrcmpA
.text:00401343                 cmp     eax, 0
.text:00401346                 jz      short loc_40134C
.text:00401348                 xor     eax, eax
.text:0040134A                 jmp     short loc_40134E
.text:0040134C ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:0040134C
.text:0040134C loc_40134C:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_4012F9+4Dj
.text:0040134C                 mov     eax, ecx
```

затем
если cmp     eax, 0
serial не верен, иначе -верен.

Впервые сталкиваюсь с этими штучками))) Задание легкое... Но я не ас и не очень понимаю что там происходит...
Можете в общих чертах описать что происходит при проверке серийника?

Comment: Привет!
Может для этой задачки использовать OllyDBG, а IDA Pro для нее слишком громоздка.
После сравнения должен идти этот jz short loc_40134C, можно его просто на безусловный заменить ))
По поводу описания того, как именно происходит формирование сериал номера, тут надо прогнать все под отладчиком (как говорил выше лучше под Olly), из этого листинга не очень понятно. Пройтись пошагово и смотреть стек, ставить точки останова и анализировать

Comment: @ghost rider, патч - не труъ метод. В данном случае - это все равно что разобрать кубик Рубика на запчасти и потом склеить, или просто взять краску и покрасить каждую грань в один цвет :)

По поводу отладки - иногда нужно уметь отлаживать код в уме.

Comment: @insolor - согласен можно и в уме отлаживать код, главное чтоб stackoverflow не произошел ))

Comment: Теперь получить патч на Хешкоде стало ещё проще!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На входе функции имеем имя (String1), введенный код (String), в цикле из имени получаем правильный серийник (String2) и сравниваем его с введенным.
Код генерации серийника (String2):

```
// 4012FE
char *esi = String; // lea esi, String
char *edi = String2; // lea edi, String2
char al=0, cl=0, bl = 0x1A; // xor eax, eax; xor ecx, ecx; mov bl, 1Ah
// loc_401310:
while(*esi) // cmp byte ptr [esi], 0; jz short loc_40132A
{
    al = *esi; // mov al, [esi]
    al += cl; // add al, cl
    al ^= cl; // xor al, cl
    al %= bl; // div bl; shr ax, 8
    al += 0x41; // add al, 41h
    *edi = al; // mov [edi], al
    edi++; // inc edi
    esi++; // inc esi
    cl++; // inc ecx // упростил
} // jmp short loc_401310
// loc_40132A:
*edi = 0; // mov byte ptr [edi], 0
// Тут еще была проверка длины введенного имени, для упрощения опускаем
if(strcmp(String1,String2)==0) ...; // push String1; Push String2; call lstrcmpA
```

Comment: Похоже я совсем тугой по этой теме... Не понял как вы получили код генерации серийника( не понятен смысл цикла...  Какая вообще идея, есть код генерации, и имя => как отсюда следует серийник?

Comment: Так это всё в ассемблере и написано. Тут переведено в псевдокод на си.

Comment: @Alerr, сейчас добавлю комменты к строкам. Переводил вручную. Идея кода в том, что берется введенное имя, над каждым очередным его символом производятся какие-то манипуляции, в результате получается очередной символ серийника.